# Missing Dependency in SAGA. Orfeo Toolbox does not work

Tags: qgis, saga, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform segmentation from Orfeo Toolbox (QGIS last version 2.2), whenever I try to use the toolbox, I get the following message:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
>
> Output labeled image: D:/ERDAS_examples/Sardegna
> 1954/segmnentation.tif
>
> The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that
> they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
>
> Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were
> not created as expected

The same when I try to use SAGA toolbox:

> Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-(
>
> This algorithm requires SAGA to be run.Unfortunately, it seems that
> SAGA is not installed in your system, or it is not correctly
> configured to be used from QGI,
>
> Click here to know more about how to install and configure SAGA to be
> used with QGIS

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are encountering [Error in OTB segmentation with certain projections](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7855) and the proposed workaround is to work in WGS84.

For using OTB, a workaround is to install the stand alone Monteverdi software (directly based on OTB), also available from [OSGEO4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). Using the task specific OTB applications could also be more "robust".  (see the [cookbook](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu41.html#x63-900004.3.2) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

Under `Processing -> Options and Configuration`, `Data Providers`,

take a look at the SAGA entry. Sometimes, the entries for the folder of the application is empty.

For Orfeo Toolbox, the message is different, so QGIS has found the application, but the output file is not generated. You have to take a closer look at the log OTB produces.